# Primefaces - How to show and hide two different `panel` components in one location

Tags: jsf, primefaces, panel

I need your help in showing and hiding two different `panel` components in one location. Currently in the page at the top, I am allowing the user to select one choice from the `selectOneRadio` component.

Below the `selectOneRadio` component, I am placing two different `panel` components where I am using the rendered attribute to show or hide the `panel` based on the selection. For example if the user selects the first option, the first `panel` will be shown and the second will be hidden and if he chose the second option, the first `panel` component will be hidden and the second will be shown.

However, the issue which I am facing is if the user selects the second option that the first panel will be hidden and there will be a huge space as I am placing `panelGrid` components and `inputText` components under the first `panel` and below it, the second `panel` will be shown. So how can I make the second `panel` to be shown in the location of the first `panel`.

Here is the JSF code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
                <p:outputLabel value="Please Select a Request Type:"/>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <p:selectOneRadio id="request" layout="pageDirection" value="#{user.requestType}">
        <td width="50%">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Certificates for Other" itemValue="O"/>
         </td>
         <td width="50%">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Certificates for Banks" itemValue="B"/>
         </td>
     <p:ajax event="change" update="@form" listener="#{user.firstToggle}"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>
     </tr>
</table>

<p:panel id="toggleable" header="Certificates for Other" toggleable="true" rendered="#{user.firstTogg}" widgetVar="panel" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td height="100%"> 
                <p:selectOneMenu label="c_e_language_hr" id="c_e_language_hr" disabled="#{user.firstTogg}"    value="#{user.employmentCertificateLanguageHr}">
                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please Select a Language" itemValue="F"/>
                 <f:selectItems value="#{user.ceLangDesc}" var="celang" itemLabel="#{celang.langDesc}" itemValue="#{celang.langCd}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</p:panel>
<p:panel id="toggleable1" header="Certificates for Banks" toggleable="true" rendered="#{user.secondToggle}" widgetVar="panel1" style="margin-bottom:15px">

</p:panel>
```

Comment: @BalusC No, they are not. Do you want the full code to be placed?

Comment: @BalusC Please check the updated

Comment: Not a jsf problem. Check the css that makes this happen and fix it (`<td height="100%">` might be the culprit)